# Logon denied error when loading data from Oracle to pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, oracle11g

Please note that I am new to pySpark, and feel free to let me know if I am missing any detail.

Running on Windows 10, with python3.7 installed
Command being used to run pyspark: `pyspark --jars "C:\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\ojdbc6.jar"`

Code that I am trying to execute in pyspark shell:

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
sqlctx = SQLContext(sc)
with open("new1", "r") as f:
    query = f.read()

df = sqlctx.read.format("jdbc").options(url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:sid", 
driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", dbtable=query).load()
```

I am pretty sure, url is correct, window login that i'm using has access to database as it works fine with cx_Oracle and I can access DB using PL/SQL client.

Error:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 172, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o39.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:675)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:448)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:383)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:776)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:432)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.scala:45)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the example way to access oracle from spark, where you are using user and pwd seperately.

see [read-data-from-oracle-database-with-apache-spark](https://dzone.com/articles/read-data-from-oracle-database-with-apache-spark)

```
myDF = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:username/password@//hostname:portnumber/SID") \
    .option("dbtable", "hr.emp") \
    .option("user", "db_user_name") \
    .option("password", "password") \
    .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver") \
    .load()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. this gives me the same error, the difference is options vs option and it gives the same result. Also it has additional user and password option which I have tried already, I still get the same error.  Moreover, I think by default it should get windows credentials (I might be wrong about this)

Comment: there is no by default. you have to provide the credentials. "this gives me the same error" there is some fatal mistake you are doing re check... it should work.

Comment: you are right. The id that I initially was using corporate windows credentials which was causing the issue apparently. Regular DB user with same access did the trick